# Why does fetch not always access nodejs route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I am building a nodejs server that is supposed to give images to my frontend. So I am using fetch to grab the data from my express routes but to me it seems like fetch doesn't always grab data.

```
app.get('/image', function (req, res) {
        helper2 = __dirname + "/pics/test/" + helper[counter];
        console.log(helper2);
        res.sendFile(helper2);
});
```

This is my route to access images.

```
function getImg() {
    fetch('/data', {})
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((response) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                a[i] = response[i][0];
                b[i] = response[i][1];
                c[i] = response[i][2];
                d[i] = response[i][3];
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            // Use Data, draw part of Image
            }
            img.src = '/image';
        })
}
```

This is how I fetch some data linked to the images and how I set the images source to my endpoint. I have multiple images and after a set amount I want to send a POST request to my nodejs server and change the counter in the /image router to get a different set of pictures.

```
    function next() {
         fetch('/data', {
             method: "POST",
             headers: {
                 'Accept': 'application/json',
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             },
             body: JSON.stringify({
                 counter: counter
             })
         }).then(() => {
             counter2 = 0;
         })
     }
     getImg();
  }
```

Here I pass the counter to set it in my nodejs route. I know I left out some code, but it actually already does everything it needs to do. The problem is that when I use the next function to go to the next image it doesn't always ask my /image for the image. As you can see in my /image route if have the `console.log(helper2);`
and sometimes when I run my app and click through a few images it will show me the path every time I see a new image, but sometimes it will load the image but the console.log won't trigger so I know it isn't fetching the /image. This is what messes up my app because I am passing the counter back to my backend and changing it but then my frontend doesn't fetch /images and the image doesn't change. I presume it has something to do with the way Firefox maybe stores the data it fetches, but I really can't figure out how to force it to fetch the image every time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are expecting the calls to occur synchronously and right now the two calls are made asynchronously, so the counter you update in the front end is not available for the second fetch.

if you want `getImg` to be called after the fetch in next() is complete, you need to move `getImg()` into the .then() clause of that fetch, or use the `async / await` keywords in front of

```
function next() {
         fetch('/data', {
             method: "POST",
             headers: {
                 'Accept': 'application/json',
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             },
             body: JSON.stringify({
                 counter: counter
             })
         }).then(() => {
             counter2 = 0;
             getImg();
         })
     }
```

or

```
async function next() {
         await fetch('/data', {
             method: "POST",
             headers: {
                 'Accept': 'application/json',
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             },
             body: JSON.stringify({
                 counter: counter
             })
         });
       counter2 = 0;
       getImg();
     }
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help appreciate it! But sadly this did not solve the problem. For some reason my fetch /data where I have the img.src='/image' doesn't always fetch /image. That's where the problem should be but I have no Idea why or how to bypass this.